# Приложение не запускается после превышения запросов в минуту с openweathermap

Tags: python, python-3.x, openweathermap

Есть код приложения, в котором показывается погода на сегодняшний день и на текущую неделю, однако во время работы с кодом внезапно появилась ошибка **Status code 429 from http://ipinfo.io/json: ERROR - 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: http://ipinfo.io/json**.
Я так понял, эта ошибка появляется, если с сайта openweathermap произошло больше 60 запросов в минуту(хотя я не знаю как я мог сделать в одиночку больше 60 запросов за минуту). Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при наступлении этой ошибки приложение все равно продолжало свою работу, но просто не показывая погоду?

Если надо, то обновлю вопрос и выложу код приложения.

Вот код приложения, ошибка появлялась на 25 строке(хотя на следующий день после ошибки все работало нормально):

```
# weather v 1.0
import requests
import geocoder
import datetime

API_KEY = 'cf64041397ba4128f1a2426cd3e11397'
HOST  = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/'
DAYS =  [
        {'num': 0 , 'title':'понедельник', 'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 1 , 'title':'вторник',     'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [1,2,3,4,5,6,0], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 2 , 'title':'среда',       'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [2,3,4,5,6,0,1], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 3 , 'title':'четверг',     'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [3,4,5,6,0,1,2], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 4 , 'title':'пятница',     'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [4,5,6,0,1,2,3], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 5 , 'title':'суббота',     'active': False , 'color' : '#d0130d', 'order': [5,6,0,1,2,3,4], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 6 , 'title':'воскресенье', 'active': False , 'color' : '#d0130d', 'order': [6,0,1,2,3,4,5], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
]

def today():
    g = geocoder.ip('me')
    city = g.city
    lat = g.lat
    lon = g.lng
    req = requests.get(f'{HOST}weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric&lang=ru').json()
    res={
        'city' : req['name'],
        'dis'  : req['weather'][0]['description'],
        'temp' : int(round(req['main']['temp'])),
        'feels': str(round(req['main']['feels_like']))+ '°С',
        'pressure': str(round(req['main']['pressure'] / 1000 * 750 , 2)),
        'wind' : req['wind'],
    }
    return res
    

def week():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    DAYS[today.weekday()]['active'] = True
    

    for i in DAYS:
        if DAYS[today.weekday()]['active']:
            order = DAYS[today.weekday()]['order']
        g = geocoder.ip('me')
        city = g.city
        lat  = g.lat
        lon  = g.lng

        req = requests.get(f'{HOST}onecall?/exclude=daily&lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric&lang=ru').json()
        res = [DAYS[i] for i in order]

        for i in req['daily']:
            index = req['daily'].index(i)
            if index ==7:
                break
            res[index]['temp'] = round(i['temp']['day'])
            res[index]['type'] = i['weather'][0]['description']

        return res
```

Comment: приложите код и укажите на каком этапе и строке возникает ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Полина из IPinfo на связи :) Лимит устанавливается на день или на месяц, он зависит от вида запроса: с аутентификацией (токен) или без. Если вы делаете запрос без своего уникального токена, то вы попадаете в общий пул пользователей и лимит может исчерпаться очень быстро. Если вы делаете запрос со своим токеном, то даже на бесплатном плане лимит это 50 000 запросов в месяц. Как только лимит исчерпывается, мы начинаем возвращать 429 ошибку.

Comment: А на какое время я лишусь возможности делать запросы при превышении кол-во запросов?

Comment: Лимит обновляется каждый календарный месяц, 1 числа. То есть если лимит будет превышен 15 сентября, снова можно будет делать запросы 1 октября.